# Use of "to" in "opposite to". Is it correct?

Tags: prepositions

- Our house is opposite the supermarket.
- Our house is opposite to the supermarket.

Which one is correct? Can you please explain the reason?

Answer (score 5):

> Our house is opposite the supermarket

This is correct because the definition of “opposite” as an adjective not employing a preposition is:

> **having a position on the other or further side of something; facing something, esp. something of the same type.**
>   *"a crowd gathered on the opposite side of the street"*
>   
> <sub>synonyms:  facing, opposing, reverse
>   
> <sub>Source: [Google result for “define opposite”](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+opposite)</sub></sub>

Longman's Dictionary provides some useful notes on this topic:

> Do not say that one thing is ***opposite to*** or ***opposite of*** another. 
> Say that one thing is ***opposite*** another:     *There's a car park opposite the hotel.*
>   
> <sub><sub>Source: [Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English, definition of “opposite”](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/opposite_1) (emphasis mine)</sub></sub>

---

Further notes:

I think most people would interpret your statement as saying “our house is across the street from the supermarket”, but technically this word should be reserved for objects that are *facing* one another. In the case of the supermarket and your house, this would require the main entrance of each structure to face that of the other. Your exact meaning could be made more clear by mentioning the sides of whatever runs between your house and the supermarket, as sides of a straight path are always opposite one another. Assuming, again, that it's a street that lies between your house and this supermarket, you could write:

> Our house is on the opposite side of the street from the supermarket.

Or avoid the term altogether and write it as I did above:

> Our house is across the street from the supermarket.

Comment: Your answer (source: *Longman's Dictionary*) disagrees with the other answer (source: *Longman's Grammar*). I would have guessed this is British/American difference, but mustn't Longman be one or the other?

Comment: @Peter Writing that “to” is “often unnecessary” and recommending that you “do not say” it doesn’t strike me as a disagreement.

Comment: And what is going on is that in 1800, most people included the *"to"*, while today nearly everybody drops it. No BrE/AmE difference; [See Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=house+opposite+to%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Fhouse+opposite%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Chouse+opposite+to%3Aeng_us_2012%2Fhouse+opposite%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28house%20opposite%20to%3Aeng_gb_2012%20/%20house%20opposite%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28house%20opposite%20to%3Aeng_us_2012%20/%20house%20opposite%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 2):

Both are correct. However, *to* is often omitted.

According to *Longman English Grammar*, Appendix 25.30,

> **25.30 'opposite (to)'**
>   ***Opposite*** can be used as an adverb;
>     *Where's the bank? - It's **opposite.***
>   Or it can be used as a preposition, with or without to (though *to* is often unnecessary):
>     *There's a bank **opposite (to) my office**.*
>   [...]

This is also in agreement with Quirk's grammar. According to *A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language* (Quirk et al. 1985), p.680,

> Opposite means 'facing' and has optional to:
>   *Her house is opposite (to) mine.*

So both of your sentences *"Our house is opposite the supermarket,"* and *"Our house is opposite to the supermarket,"* are correct. Also note the meaning of *opposite* in the sense of "facing each other",

> preposition: **[opposite](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20opposite)**
>     in a position on the other side of a specific area from; facing.

Comment: Barrie England answered a similar question and mentioned the use of *opposite to* on ELL once too. See http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/10188/3281.

Comment: Wow. What a cool explanation! Hey Damkerng, Can you please tell me some sources where I can brush up my English grammar skills? I am not naive for English, but still I want to brush up my knowledge. Any e-book or blog or something else?

Comment: @hellodear2 I decided to buy PEU (Practical English Usage) to improve my grammar skill and I found it really useful. (Questions on ELL can be good motivation to pick up grammar books, which I already have a few, but never used it much.) As for web resources, there are too many. I usually started by searching Google, and usually ended up reading Grammar Girl's posts. :-) Beyond that, I usually read and listen to NPR news.

Comment: In two months how can you earn so much reputation points? So, how should I improve my grammar skills? please tell some ways to me.

Comment: @hellodear2 I asked and answered questions. :-) I'm trying this: Reading fast and slow. I read fast to understand what I wand to read. Then I read the same thing once again, but this time I read it one sentence at a time, and make a note of those grammar points I can observe. That's my technique. Feel free to use it if it's useful to you.

Comment: But like this, how will you know about rules and many other things about grammar? I don't think so.

Comment: Your answer (source: *Longman's Grammar*) disagrees with the other answer (source: *Longman's Dictionary*).  I would have guessed this is British/American difference, but mustn't Longman be one or the other?

Comment: Actually, it's not a BrE/AmE difference, but a time difference ... people are dropping the *to* more and more frequently. [See Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=house+opposite+to%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Fhouse+opposite%3Aeng_gb_2012%2Chouse+opposite+to%3Aeng_us_2012%2Fhouse+opposite%3Aeng_us_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28house%20opposite%20to%3Aeng_gb_2012%20/%20house%20opposite%3Aeng_gb_2012%29%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28house%20opposite%20to%3Aeng_us_2012%20/%20house%20opposite%3Aeng_us_2012%29%3B%2Cc0)

Comment: @PeterShor Thank you for the Ngrams, which confirms my speculation that the "opposite to" is more and more dropped. My main motive to post this answer is to assure the OP that both forms are possible, though Tyler's answer already gives a big hint that which usage is preferred. So I believe that the two answers reinforce each other. (And so are your comments too).